# Any way to use a parameter rather than a variable in a foreach loop in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl

I have two Connection Managers. One is called Products and it is at the "Project level".  I have a package called "Import CSV."  I'd like to have a foreach loop which will go out and read a few files and add them to a SQL Server table for use further down the road.  This requires the foreach loop container, inputting a File path string, and then using that variable in the expression of the "Products" connection manager properties.

The issue I am running into is that the Products connection is at the Project level, so it can't see any variables with the scope of "User".  But the "Variable Mapping" in the foreach loop editor only seems to let me do variables.  Is there a way to input the scope under "Variable" in Variable mapping so that it can use params instead of variables? I know I can drop the "Products" connection to not be a project level item anymore but was looking for a better solution. Thanks!

Comment: Might be quick an dirty, but why don't you add a variable to your package, which receives the project parameter via expression? This way you can access the value of the parameter via a variable...

Comment: I'm not sure how to do what you are suggesting, though I've been trying for a while to implement.  The issue is that the foreach loop drives the process, and while I think I can do what you are suggesting, I'd need the parameter to change but the foreach loop will be looking for the variable.  Maybe I don't quite understand, but not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are read-only during the execution of a package. That's why you cannot use one as a parameter in the Foreach Enumerator - that'd be a write operation.

As you've also discovered, project level connection managers can only have expressions that reference project parameters. This is *likely* due to concurrency issues (Package 1 attempts to set the database name to tempdb and Package 2 attempts to set the database to master - which one is more correct?). Or it's just an extension of parameter's being read-only principal - the project connection manager can only be modified by read-only values so it's stable during the execution of the package. There might be documentation calling out the why of this design but it is the design and unlikely to change.

If you attempt to manually type the local variables into the expression builder (here I was trying to populate `InitialCatalog` from the local variable `DatabaseName`) you will get an out of scope evaluation error.

> TITLE: Expression Builder
>
> Expression cannot be evaluated.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%C2%AE%20Visual%20Studio%C2%AE&ProdVer=15.8.28010.2046&EvtSrc=Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Controls.TaskUIFramework.TaskUIFrameworkSR&EvtID=FailToEvaluateExpression&LinkId=20476

> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
> The variable "User::DatabaseName" was not found in the Variables collection. The variable might not exist in the correct scope.

> Attempt to parse the expression "@[User::DatabaseName]" failed and returned error code 0xC00470A6. The expression cannot be parsed. It might contain invalid elements or it might not be well-formed. There may also be an out-of-memory error.

### How can I get what I want?

Option 1. Demote Products from a project level connection manager to a package level connection manager. Increases maintenance complexity for a multi-package deployment but it solves the development problem. If this is a file connection manager - this is likely the better design. I rarely share file (Excel, txt, csv) between packages due to the exacting nature of dataflow metadata. Database connections however are commonly shared because the metadata specific items (tables) are at a lower level of abstraction so no metadata headaches.

And that's it. I thought you might be able to hack your way around it with a sub package and parameters but those too will be out of scope.

Comment: I figured this might be the only way.  It is a CSV file and really primarily read by a single package, so I think your caution is correct.